# Samsung LCD screen flickering and inverted color

Tags: laptop, lcd, optical-drive

There is a DVD disc that stuck inside the optical drive, and the optical drive cannot be opened. After doing some tricks to eject it out, the disc somehow pushed & attached itself inside. But opening the optical drive is now Ok and has been fixed.

A couple of minutes, I able to get the disc that was pushed inside. But leaving me a problem with the screen. My LCD output was Ok back then.

**What is the cause of this?**

[image: Start Up]

[Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H5Hx.jpg) , [Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faupk.jpg),

[image: Lock Screen]

I'm planning to open this Samsung laptop - my first time. And locate the cable, LCD cable.

Comment: All I can see on the photos is that colors are inverted. Do you mean that or is the screen actually flickering?

Comment: It is really flickering, I will add another photo. Start up photo. The flicker is somehow lessen when login.

Comment: Dynamic phenomena like flickering aren't visible on still images. Try to make a video and make sure the effect is visible before uploading it. For example the only unusual thing that I can see in these photos is that colors are inverted, I would never guess that something is flickering just by looking at them. So please check if the video actually shows the issue.

Comment: Setting aside the flickering, if this is just inverted. Is the fault in the cable? Since the disk was pushed inside. I believed it hit some parts inside.

Comment: Possibly. That's the optimistic scenario. Replacing display cable isn't too much of a hassle. If something was damaged on the motherboard though, then fixing it may be *very* expensive, like at least half of laptop's price expensive.

Comment: I just project it in other LCD screen, and yes it show that the laptop LCD screen is defective. I try to tweak it inside. Thank you very much.